# Videos not playing in Chrome or Opera

Tags: video, google-chrome, opera

I recently installed Opera and Chrome again on Ubuntu, but video players on sites will not work...but do work on Firefox

[It will look like this, but with the audio working fine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67tNn.png)

[If I pop it out however, it works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iR9nI.png) at least for Opera.

It's not just Youtube, [this video doesn't work either.](http://rspec.codeschool.com/levels/1)

I also figured out that non-HTML5 videos such as [this](http://wwwns.akamai.com/hdnetwork/demo/flash/default.html) work though.

Any help? Thanks.

**EDIT Disabling HTML5 video for Youtube on Chrome fixed the problem, but still kind of a half solution.**

Comment: check if flash player is installed open chrome and type chrome://plugins/

Comment: Just checked, it is.

Comment: are you install flash on ubuntu or you work without installing

Comment: to install flash open terminal and type sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer

Comment: Still nothing, I did a similar recommendation to that with sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree someone said on Reddit.

Comment: you tried flashplugin-installer ??

Comment: Yeah I tried that as well and still no luck. I think it has something to do with HTML5, because when I disabled HTML5 video on Youtube it worked.

Comment: is firefox working fine?

Comment: Yes it is working.

Comment: what about chrome incognito ?

Comment: Please update your question with the following information: your OS version, your video card, the driver you are using (proprietary or free). Thanks. :)

Comment: "the driver you are using (proprietary or free)" that was the issue, thanks for y'alls help

Answer (score 2):

Just install `ffmpeg` codecs for Chromium:

```
sudo apt install chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra
```

This should fix playing HTML5 videos in Chromium and all its derivates (Opera, Vivaldi).

Answer (score 1):

Had to change the graphics driver from an open source X.Org X to the NVIDIA one. Rebooted and worked fine.

Under Software & Updates in System Settings

[image]